# How to create a Grails app with Webpack and VueJS?

Tags: grails, webpack, vue.js

Im trying to create a Grails application (Grails 3.2.9), combined with a JS client based on VueJS 2.x and webpack.

I know there is a Webpack profile in grails, but nothing about Vuejs. Is there any documentation somewhere, any guide or sample project I could look into?

I have been able to generate a Grails app with webpack using Grails, another app with Grails and VueJS (VueJS integrated inside Grails' GSP), and a third app with webpack and VueJs (using vue-loader), but never managed to create an app with the three of them.

Comment: did you solve this somehow?

Comment: No, I haven't. Worse, the project I work on has changed its framework!

Comment: added git link in the answer

Answer (score 2):

There is a [**grails guide**](http://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html) you can follow to create custom gradle task and execute those as you need. Anyway I've created a `grails 3`-`vuejs 2` starter project from that guide. 
**Git repo link:** https://github.com/mamunsrdr/bootvue.git.
Please follow the readme.

**Edit:** just a few days ago grails released new way of doing this, called application forge just like spring boot. You can follow [**this link**](http://start.grails.org). There you can pick one of many profiles, `webpack` is one of them.